# jQuery autocomplete: not getting any results. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/index.php/welcome/get_client/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: "{}",
      success: function(data) {
          var datafromServer = data.split(",");
          ("#search_client").autocomplete({
              source: datafromServer
          });
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(textStatus);
      }
    });

});
</script>
```

Above is my jQuery code. I actually got it from a tutorial, but for the life of me, I can't seem to get it to work and now I'm wondering if it's my json result from PHP.

My PHP looks like this:

```
function get_client()
{
    $this->db->select('name')->from('clients');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($query->result());
}
```

When I echo it, it looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Testing"},{"name":"Testing1"},{"name":"test11"},{"name":"test4"},{"name":"Testing21"},{"name":"Just Testing"},{"name":"testy"}]
```

I do get the following JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'data.split' [undefined] is not a function.
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: Do you set content type application/json in your HTTP response header in your PHP?

Comment: have you tried hitting the url directly?

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts are loaded?

Comment: Yes, I am. My PHP is pretty simple: $this->db->select('name')->from('clients'); $query = $this->db->get(); header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode($query->result());

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? The `var datafromServer = data.d.split(",")` part looks suspiciousness, it seems that data does not have `d` attribute.

Comment: I do have this JS error: TypeError: Result of expression 'data.split' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: Also you might find jquery autocomplete (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) useful.

Comment: your data get back to server and jquery parser JSON into variable "data" that is why split does not work. Data is an object. Not String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this time, the problem was simple: I left the dollar sign off this:

```
("#search_client").autocomplete({
```

Answer (score 1):

The data result does not have a property `d` so `data.d.split(",");` would be empty.
instead try:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/index.php/welcome/get_client/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        success: function(data) {                
            ("#search_client").autocomplete({
                source: data
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** actually there is no need to split the data....

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: Result of expression '("#search_client").autocomplete' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: @dallen looks like you are missing the autocomplete script declaration

Comment: But I'm using the same JS/CSS references used in the example: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete . If I copy/paste that code in my editor and test it, it works fine. So it should be there...

Comment: @dallen you are returning a set of paired values, you should try returning just the values in an array: ["test1","tesing",tester"]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the mime-type of your response too, it should be text/json, or application/json I believe.

**Edit** I'm leaning towards application/json, see [the right JSON content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)